# It's true that $ |\log^2(z)| \leqslant |\log(R)|^2 + |i \arg(z)|^2 $ where $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, inequality

In some residue integral, when one have to prove that an integral 
vanish at infinity, I've found in some textbooks the inequality:

$$ |\log^2(z)| \leqslant |\log(R)|^2 + |i\ \arg(z)|^2 $$

Where $z= Re^{i \arg(z)} \in \mathbb{C}$.

How can I prove this ? And furthermore, there is a more general procedure to find inequality involving $| \log^p(z)|$ ? Thanks

Comment: For any complex number $w= u+iv$ ($u, v \in \Bbb R$), you have $|w^2| = |w|^2 = u^2 + v^2$. Now apply that to $w = \log z = \log|z| + i \arg z$.

Comment: Ok, I've proven in fact that, if $z^n = |z|^n e^{i n \vartheta} $ then $ |z^n| = |z|^n|e^{in \vartheta}| = |z|^n $, so your comment is really useful, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The last one is a well known inequalitie, i think it's the triangle inequalitie

Comment: And is it fair to do $ |log^2(z)| = |log(z)|^2 $ ? And also, I think $log^2(z) \neq log^2(|z|) + (i\theta)^2 $

Comment: Ok, I've understood your reasoning, even if it should be more specific, thanks :)